# how to send data from html form to php using ajax using upload also

Tags: php, ajax

I am new to php  and jquery so I am not having any idea how to post data using ajax and especially file upload system .I have php codes for uploading but in my project it may need to do with ajax.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function dataSubmit(formid){

       //alert(formid);
    //   $('.result').html('<p style="display:block; text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Process...</span> Processing</p>');
        var action = $(formid).attr('action');

        var fd = new FormData();
           var file_data = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files; // for multiple files
           for(var i = 0;i<file_data.length;i++){
               fd.append("file_"+i, file_data[i]);
           }
           var other_data = $('form').serializeArray();
           $.each(other_data,function(key,input){
               fd.append(input.name,input.value);
           });
           $.ajax({
               url: action,
               data: fd,
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,
               type: 'POST',
               success: function(data){
                   console.log(data);
                   var tag = 'Successfull';

                     if(data.indexOf(tag) != -1){
                         eagleToast(data, 5000,'green');
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         eagleToast(data, 5000,'red');
                     }
               }
           });

    }
```

i wish this code will work.

Answer (score -1):

You should do it with Javascript/jQuery in a function.
I usually do that with jQuery this way:

```
$.post("your_php_file.php",
{
value1: $("#id1").val(),
value2: $("#id2").val(),
value3: $("#id3").val()
})
.done(function (data) {
  alert(data); //shows message
  window.location.reload(); //reload page 
});
```